# Android notification programmed

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have build a simple app that show a notification when i click on a button. How can show a programmed notify?

The code that i call is:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setTicker("Notifica")
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
    .setContentTitle("Notifica")
    .setContentText("Hai una notifica!")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), 0));
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify("interstitial_tag", 1, builder.build());
```

Comment: Seems you need `AlarmManager`

Comment: you need an alarm manager to do that,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in bundle with [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

At first you must create pending intent and register it with [AlarmManager.set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) somewhere.
And then create your broadcast receiver and receive that intent.

Update: here is the code I have promised.

At first you need to create broadcast receiver.

```
public class NotifyHandlerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION = "me.pepyakin.defferednotify.action.NOTIFY";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
             Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setTicker("Notifica")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setContentTitle("Notifica")
                .setContentText("Hai una notifica!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), 0));

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify("interstitial_tag", 1, builder.build());
       }
    }
}
```

This is your broadcast receiver that can handle notification requests. For it can work, you must register it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you don't do it, Android won't be able to handle your notification request.

Just add `<receiver/>` declaration into your `<application/>` tag.

```
    <receiver android:name=".NotifyHandlerReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="me.pepyakin.defferednotify.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Take a note, that action name be exactly as defined in `NotifyHandlerReceiver.ACTION`.

Then you can use this code

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY = 1;

public void scheduleNotification(long delayTimeMs) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long currentTimeMs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    PendingIntent pendingNotifyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY,
            new Intent(NotifyHandlerReceiver.ACTION),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, currentTimeMs + delayTimeMs, pendingNotifyIntent);
}
```

from your activity to start a notification delayed on `delayTimeMs` amount of milliseconds.

Comment: Oh, sorry. `public static final int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY = 1;`. It is simple request code for that pending intent. Needed for take control of this intent in future, for example, if you wish to update it.

Comment: It seems that you writed
`<receiver android:name="me.pepyakin.defferednotify.action.NOTIFY">`. Try to review my example more carefully.

Comment: Now i have no error but the notification doesn't start. I have tried with 1000msecond..

Comment: ok, here is the code. Hope this will help https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgu0lfwgue21rdt/DeferedNotifyProject.zip